# How to bind JSON data with Kendo Grid

Tags: c#, json, wcf, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Using MY WCF Service I am exposing JSON data:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
 List<ProductDetails> GetProductDetails();
```

Here is a sample of the returned JSON:

> {"d":[{"__type":"ProductDetails:#NWProducts","Discount":0,"OrderId":10248,"ProductId":11,"UnitPrice":14.0000,"quanity":12},{"__type":"ProductDetails:#NWProducts","Discount":0,"OrderId":10248,"ProductId":42,"UnitPrice":9.8000,"quanity":10},{"__type":"ProductDetails:#NWProducts","Discount":0,"OrderId":10248,"ProductId":72,"UnitPrice":34.8000,"quanity":5},{"__type":"ProductDetails:#NWProducts","Discount":0,"OrderId":10249,"ProductId":14,"UnitPrice":18.6000,"quanity":9},{"__type":"ProductDetails:#NWProducts","Discount":0,"OrderId":10249,"ProductId":51,"UnitPrice":42.4000,"quanity":40}

Trying to bind that to Kendo Grid using :

```
   <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "json",
                            transport: {
                                read: "http://localhost/KendoServices/Web/GetProductDetails"
                            },
                            pageSize: 10
                        },
                        groupable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: {
                            refresh: true,
                            pageSizes: true,
                            buttonCount: 5
                        },
                        columns: [{
                            field: "OrderId",
                            title: "OrderId",
                            width: 140
                        }, {
                            field: "ProductId",
                            title: "ProductId",
                            width: 190
                        }, {
                            field: "UnitPrice",
                            title: "UnitPrice"
                        }, {
                            field: "quanity",
                            width: 110
                        }]
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

For some reason, I'm unable to see any data on grid. There might be something wrong with the way I'm trying to bind my data.

Comment: Just an offer...try to add `ServerOperation:false`

Answer (score 2):

The resultant JSON is the culprit here.  The kendo dataSource by default looks for the return object to have the items in an array called results. Simple to fix.  Just need to define where the data is in the response JSON object.

```
dataSource: {
    transport: {
        read: {
             url: "http://localhost/KendoServices/Web/GetProductDetails",
             dataType: 'json'
        }
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    schema: {
        data: function(response) {
            return response.d;
        }
    }
},
```

--Edit...
Whoops, missed something else. Your `type: 'json'` should be inside your read object, and should be `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Still Same , Not able to see any data on grid

Comment: If you put a stop on the return response.d and inspect the response object, does it have all of your JSON in it somewhere ?

Comment: Not able to Get the break Point working at response.d but can checkin Fiddler I am getting everything inside JSON

Comment: Do you mean inside transport object , if need to be inside read , Can you please update the Answer with Code?

Comment: Sorry, I'm off my game this morning.  Fixed the transport.read, it should be an object with url and dataType properties.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
dataSource: {
    transport: {
            read: {
                   url: "http://localhost/KendoServices/Web/GetProductDetails",
                   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                   dataType: "json"
                  }
    },
    schema: {
                 data: "d"
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it:

```
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {               
            transport: {
                    read: { 
                            url : pUrl,
                            dataType: "json"
                    }
            },
            pageSize:40,                
            schema: {
                data: function(response) {
                    return response.json;
                }
            }               

        },
        height: 550,
        groupable: false,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: false,
            pageSizes: false,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        columns: [
            {
                field: "SEQ_NO",
                title: "No",
                filterable: false,
                width: 120
            }, {
                field: "LOT_NO",
                title: "Lot No (INS' No)"
            }, {
                field: "TYPE",
                title: "INPUT (At 100% Burden)"
            }, {
                field: "ATTRIBUTE01",
                title: "1.0 In"
            }, {
                field: "ATTRIBUTE02",
                title: "2.0 In"
            }, {
                field: "ATTRIBUTE03",
                title: "0.05 In"
            }, {
                   field: "RESILT",
                   title: "RESILT"
            }
        ]
    });
```

[image: Code Result Example]

Comment: Outside links to images are discouraged.